# Spring AbstractRoutingDataSource is caching Datasource

Tags: spring

I have a Spring MVC application deployed as Multi-Tenant (Single Instance) on Tomcat. All users login to the same application.

User belongs to a Region, and each Region has a separate Database instance.

We are using Dynamic DataSource Routing using Spring AbstractRoutingDataSource".

This works correctly only for the first time, when User_1 from Region_1 logs into the application, Datasource_1 is correctly assigned.

But subsequently when User_2 from Reqion_2 logs into the application, AbstractRoutingDataSource never gets called and Datasource_1 gets assigned.

It looks like Spring AbstractRoutingDataSource is caching the Datasouce.

Is there a way to change this behaviour of AbstractRoutingDataSource and get it working correctly?

Comment: Please provide what you have - configs, classes etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details for a better understanding.

I think the problem might be related to changing the tenant identifier. You may have a ThreadLocal storage to store the tenant identifier.

```
public class ThreadLocalStorage {

    private static ThreadLocal<String> tenant = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setTenantName(String tenantName) {
        tenant.set(tenantName);
    }

    public static String getTenantName() {
        return tenant.get();
    }
}
```

`AbstractRoutingDataSource` should use this to retrieve the tenantId

```
public class TenantAwareRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return ThreadLocalStorage.getTenantName();
    }
}
```

And you should set the tenantId on each request for the current thread that is handling the request so that the following operations will be done on the correct database. For you may add a Spring Security filter to extract the tenant identifier from JWT token or from host subdomain.